# Can the overall percentage override the individual ones?

Tags: puzzle

Suppose I have 2 white bags A and B, and 2 black bags C and D. All these bags only contain a bunch of cool beans and bad beans.

Bag A has a greater % of cool beans than C. Bag B has a greater % of cool beans than D. I combine the two white bags into a giant white bag and black bags into a giant black bag. Is it possible for the % of cool beans in the giant white bag is less than that of the giant black bag?

I don't think this is possible because the individual components already maintain that the white bag will have a greater % of cool beans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following scenario:

A has 1 cool bean out of 100 total.
B has 1 cool beans out of 1 total.
C has 1 cool bean out of 101 total.
D has 99 cool beans out of 100 total.

A+B: 2 cool beans out of 101 total.
C+D: 100 cool beans out of 201 total.

Comment: Oh wow, you're right! What are the conditions under which this is possible?

Comment: Intuitively: The reason this can happen is because D has many more total beans than B, so even though B has a higher percentage, D affects the overall percentage of C+D much more than B affects the overall percentage of A+B.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible: it’s called [Simpson’s paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox).